# Angular *ngFor FormArray as radio buttons

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Goal is to user push answer to answers FormArray with button click, and *ngFor radiobutton div to select what is correct answer. Want to have only input and button element to push and to render answers bellow into radio group. Have troubles to setup correctly formarray section...thank you

TS

```
questionForm: FormGroup;
answers: FormArray;


this.questionForm = this.fb.group({
      answers: this.fb.array([this.createItem()]),
      correct: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });

createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      data: ['', [Validators.required]],
      color: ['danger']
    });
  }

addAnswer() {
  this.answers = this.questionForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
  this.answers.push(this.createItem());
}
```

HTML

```
<div formArrayName="questionForm.get('answers').controls">
   <ion-card-content">
      <ion-input formControlName="data"> </ion-input>
         <ion-button [disabled]="questionForm.get('answers').invalid (click)="addAnswer()" >Add answer
         </ion-button>
   </ion-card-content>
</div>

<ion-list *ngFor="let answer of questionForm.get('answers).value; index as i">
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-radio value="{{ i }}"></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>{{ answer.data }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-4-displaying-the-form-array-in-the-template) and [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#questionnaire-data) link?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want to dynamically add questions? Do you want to dynamically add answers? If yes to the latter, how do you want to be able to write the responses? What are the radio for? Selecting one of the answers from a user point of view whereas the questions would be from an admin point of view? Please try to be more explicit and give more details

Comment: Want to have one input field and button to add answer, then to pass that answers to div below (radio button group) to check what is correct and at the end to get complete form value @maxime1992